# HTML table based on data presented in an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I need to make an HTML table based on data stored in an array.

Primarily, I have nested array which looks like this:

```
$cars=Array(

Array("DDT","Detroit","USA",

    Array(
                Array("DDT-55555","1x1","100Hp"),
                Array("DDT-66666","2x2","200Hp"),
                Array("DDT-77777","3x3","300Hp"),
                Array("DDT-77777","4x4","400Hp")
    )),


Array( "AMM","London","UK",

    Array(
                Array("AMM-888","6x6","500Hp")
    )),

);

$countries=Array();
```

Then I have an form with an option tag for the select named country:

```
echo "<form method='post' action='***.php'>

<select name='country' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
foreach($countries as $country){
        echo "<option>".$country;
}   


echo "</select></form>";
```

What I need is a HTML table which generates data from the cars-array based on what I choose from the select form, like this:

```
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Mark</th>
     <th>City</th>
     <th>Country</th>
     <th>Model</th>
     <th>Numbers</th>
     <th>Horsepower</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```

Can't make it work..

Comment: Hi Alex, so you want on your depending value from your select-form insert the table with the values in the existing arrays if I understood that correctly?

Comment: Yes basically..

Answer (score 0):

You need to check loop over every array

```
$table= array();
foreach($cars as $currCar){    
    if($currCar[$selectedValue]){
      $table = key($currCar[$selectedValue])+1;
    }    
}
if(count($table)){
echo "<tbody>";
foreach($table as $currRow){
echo "<tr>";
    foreach($currRow as $currTd){
      echo "<td>";
        $currTd;
      echo "</td>";
    }
   echo "</tr>";
}
 echo "</tbody>";
}
```

Comment: are your countries has the same key ?  from the `country` array and `cat ` array

Comment: you need to get the `value` and exchange with `$selectedValue`